# .htaccess redirect root/old/variable to root/new/same_variable

Tags: php, .htaccess

Url:

```
www.sub.example.com/old/id/345 (345 is post id)
```

Desired url:

```
www.sub.example.com/new/345
```

Tried this but doesn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/old/id/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub.example.com/new/%1 [R=302,NC]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^old/id/(.+)$ /new/%1 [R=302,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/old/id/(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/new/$1 [R=302,NC]
```

Make sure you have `mod_rewrite` allowed.